# Object methods call without parentheses

Tags: scala, dsl

Is it possible to call an object method without parentheses, after import it ?

Here is my test code, based on [this article](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/package_objects.html) by Martin Odersky:

```scala
package gardening.fruits

object PrintPlanted {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // Call method on object
    import gardening.fruits
    fruits showFruit(apple)
    fruits showFruit apple

    // Import object
    import gardening.fruits._
    showFruit(apple)

    // showFruit apple

    // Error: missing arguments for method showFruit in package fruits;
    // follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it 
    // as a partially applied function
  }
}
```

After importing the package object `fruits`, I can call the method `showFruit(apple)`, but is there any way to call the method without parentheses like the last of the code ?

I use such of methods in a little DSL and it is a bit annoying to use parentheses. All your suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, almost anything in Scala is doable:

```
package object fruits {
  val planted = List(apple, plum, banana)

  import scala.language.dynamics

  object showFruit extends Dynamic {

    private val lookupFruit = planted
        .map(f => (f.getClass.getSimpleName, f)).toMap;

    def applyDynamic(name: String)(args: Any*) = {
      realShowFruit(lookupFruit(name+"$"));
    }

    private def realShowFruit(fruit: Fruit) = {
      println(fruit.name + "s are " + fruit.color)
    }

  }
}
```

Will make your code work.

## HOW?

We are replacing the original `showFruit` method with an object. This object happens to be  [Dynamic](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.Dynamic), so:

```
showFruit apple ~~> showFruit.applyDynamic("apple")([Some param, see below])
```

Which means that we are not receiving the `apple` object, we are dealing with an `"apple"` (`String`).

So we need to lookup fruits according to their string names. I'm using a map and some nasty Java Reflection for this :). The `apple` object is actually  `gardening.fruits.apple$`, so our `f.getClass.getSimpleName` approach works.

Well, now that you know how to do what you want, please don't. This is actually a really broken workaround simulating post fix operator syntax (which is, [by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011204/scalas-postfix-ops), not advisable) .

This will put you in all sorts of trouble. Say you want to use your method like this:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import com.sevenrtc.testreflection.fruits._
    showFruit apple // won't compile
}
```

But this compiles:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import com.sevenrtc.testreflection.fruits._
    showFruit apple 
    println("Will compile!");
}
```

Why? For the same reason that this compiles:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import com.sevenrtc.testreflection.fruits._
    showFruit apple 
    ()
}
```

The result of `println` (which is `()`) is actually being passed to `applyDynamic`. So the first example is equivalent to:

```
showFruit.apple(println("Will Compile!"))
```

Comment: Thanks, the `Dynamic` trait is what I was looking for ! The `()` in your last example are a bit annoying... It would be great to write only `showFruit apple`. I will try to use an external DSL that is more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

No that is not possible. `e1 op e2` is a so-called infix operation and equivalent to `e1.op(e2)`. This does not work when the receiver (`e1`) is left out. For the same reason you can't write things like `println "hello"`, either.

Comment: Actually, [you can hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3617550/664577) for a broken `println` too :).