# Calling methods with parameters without using parentheses

Tags: scala

I am using the following `implicit class` in order to call a function which would otherwise take parameters without having to write the parameters in brackets:

```
scala> implicit class Print(string: String) {
     |   def echo: Unit = Console.println(string)
     | }
defined class Print

scala> "Hello world" echo
Hello world
```

However while this works, I don't really like how it looks and my goal is to get the method call in front of the input variable as I think it reads better.

Is there any simple way, without relying on external libraries, to be able to call a method before supplying the parameters and without needing brackets? Implicit classes are what I've been using so far but that doesn't have to be the final solution.

What I would like to type instead of `"Hello world" echo`:

```
scala> echo "Hello world"
```

---

**Alternatives I have tried:**

- Object with `apply` method

Requires parentheses

```
object echo {
  def apply(string: String): Unit = Console.println(string)
}

echo "Hello world" // Error: ';' or newline expected
```

- **extending `Dynamic`** [[see here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3617550/8230810)

Doesn't seem to work in my version of Scala

- **Special characters** [[see here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10072777/8230810)

Looks ugly and not what I am looking for

- **Scalaz** [[see here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10074472/8230810)

Looks to do basically what my `implicit class` solution does, and I don't want any external dependencies.

---

***EDIT***

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22547055/8230810) has been pointed to as a potential solution, but again it doesn't address my issue as it relies on `Dynamic` to achieve a solution. As previously mentioned, `Dynamic` does not solve my problem for a couple of reasons:

- **It behaves funnily**

If you define a val and try to println that val, it gives you back the val's name and not its value (as pointed out by @metaphori):

```
object println extends Dynamic {
  def typed[T] = asInstanceOf[T]
  def selectDynamic(name: String) = Console.println(name)
}

val x = "hello"
println x     // prints: x
```

- **The specific example linked to did not work when I tried to recreate it** - it still gave the `';' or newline expected` error

If I just misunderstood how to implement it then I would appreciate a scalafiddle demonstrating that this solution solves my problem and will happily concede that this question is a duplicate of [the previously mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22547055/8230810), but until then I do contest it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object methods call without parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542159/object-methods-call-without-parentheses)

Comment: I disagree - edited the post to explain

Comment: No: the dynamic trick used in the other discussion does not suffer of the issue of @hüseyin-zengin; nevertheless, it has another inconvenience (related to termination of an instruction). The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22544054/2250712) to the other discussion basically is the same as mine below.
[This discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617491/why-cant-i-write-println-hello-world-in-scala/3617550#3617550) is also somewhat related. The "correct answer" to the question is basically the point that `x y` actually is `x.y`..

Comment: I had read both of those before asking my question, and while they are related I don't believe that they ask the same question - ie, "Is this possible without the use of prepending an object declaration, external dependencies or the Dynamic trait (as I have already tried this)?". It seems that the answer is "No", as you rightly answered - at least with the current version of Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve

```
echo "str"
```

since Scala is not e.g. Ruby: it syntactically requires that function invocations use parentheses.
It is not a matter of semantics or how things are implemented or what techniques are used: here is the parser that complains.
The point is that `x y` is actually interpreted as `x.y`, which means that `y` must be a method.

Refer to the [Scala Language Specification, section 6.6 Function Applications](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#function-applications):

```
SimpleExpr    ::=  SimpleExpr1 ArgumentExprs
ArgumentExprs ::=  ‘(’ [Exprs] ‘)’
                |  ‘(’ [Exprs ‘,’] PostfixExpr ‘:’ ‘_’ ‘*’ ‘)’
                |  [nl] BlockExpr
Exprs         ::=  Expr {‘,’ Expr}
```

I do not like the trick of @hüseyin-zengin since it leverages dynamic method invocations, and also does not work as expected:

```
val x = "hello"
println x     // prints: x
```

To partially achieve what you like you need to use infix operator notation

```
object run { def echo(s: String) = println(s) }

run echo "hello" // OK
run.echo "hello" // error: ';' expected but string literal found.
```

You may also use a symbol to reduce "typing" overhead (though may be perceived weirdly):

```
object > { def echo(s: String) = println(s) }

> echo "hello" // OK
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that it specified in the Specification that what I want isn't possible. How annoying that infix notation doesn't extend to something like `echo "hello"` without the object specified before it. For now, I guess I'm stuck with my backwards-Ruby `"hello" echo` then!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK only way to do something similar to what you want is extending `Dynamic` like this:

```
object println extends Dynamic {
  def typed[T] = asInstanceOf[T]
  def selectDynamic(name: String) = Console.println(name)
}
```

and using it with:

```
println `Hello World`
```

edit: of course you need to enable related features either by adding compiler parameters `-language:postfixOps` and `-language:dynamics` or by importing `scala.language.dynamics` and `scala.language.postfixOps`

Comment: This misbehaves when you do something like `val x = "hello"; println x`, as @metaphori points out. I am also curious about the `typed` function though...